# Print references at end of document

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to print out the reference list automatically at the end of the document with `\AtEndDocument{\printbibliography}`, but I end up with

> Package biblatex Warning: Please rerun LaTeX.

no matter how many times I run LaTeX. Prior to using `\AtEndDocument`, the `biblatex` code says

> Here we mustn't change the checksum if we used localnumbers from the .aux file as this means that deferred numbering is complete. Otherwise we get in an endless rerun loop because the checksum due to number changes is always different.

so presumably I need to either hack where I insert `\printbibliography` or potentially call some of the `biblatex` code again after I print the bibliography.

While the easiest solution is to probably call `\AtEndDocument{\printbibliography}` before `\usepackage{biblatex}`, I would rather avoid that order dependency. How can I robustly get the bibliography to print at the end of the document regardless of if I run the code before or after I load the `biblatex` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\AtEndDocument{\printbibliography}
\begin{document}
  \autocite{aksin}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `biblatex` does some housekeeping in `\AtEndDocument`, you should really get your `\printbibliography` in before then. Unfortunately, the `\AtEndDocument` code from `biblatex` is sprinkled throughout `biblatex.sty` and not collected in a hook of its own, so you can't easily get past `biblatex`'s stuff. I guess it might be possible to subvert `\AtBeginDocument` for `biblatex`, but I believe that the easiest solution is to issue `\AtEndDocument{\printbibliography}` before you load `biblatex`.

Comment: Mhh I wouldn't rely on the exact internals of when `biblatex` starts to do its `\AtEndDocument` stuff. That might change. But the `\preto` sounds like a plan (assuming you have nothing else in `\AtEndDocument` that would have to happen before `\printbibliography`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If you don't mind terribly, I would like to let my first comment live (even though it turned out that my belief was mistaken). I don't feel that strongly about the second comment, but would also like to opt not to delete it at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

Patching into `\@enddocumenthook` (the macro that the argument of `\AtEndDocument` is appended to) by looking for the `biblatex` housekeeping is problematic since the housekeeping is *internal* code and subject to change. Instead, I decided to prepend `\printbibliography` to `\@enddocumenthook` with `\preto` from the `etoolbox` package. This does not depend on when biblatex is loaded as it always goes in the front. If something else is trying to do something before `\printbibliography`, then it could cause problems.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\makeatletter
\preto{\@enddocumenthook}{\printbibliography}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \autocite{aksin}
\end{document}
```